# Quoting PHP Variable inside PHP Variable for Javascript Donut Chart

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I'm having a bit of a difficult time today with passing some PHP variables over to Javascript for a Donut chart. I've been messing with this for a good while now and haven't been able to figure it out yet, I've checked through posts on here as well as numerous google searches but haven't been able to find the answer yet. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm trying to push data from MySQL to a Javascript Donut chart for web referrers to a specific PHP page. The syntax for the Javascript chart is as such:

```
<script>
Morris.Donut({
element: 'css div',
data: 
[
{ label: '<?php echo($graph["referrer"]); ?>', value: '<?php echo($graph["chart"]); ?>' },
] 
});
</script>
```

The $graph['referrer'] variable holds a referrer name such as "Google.com", and the $graph['count'] variable holds the corresponding record count for the referrer name as a number, such as "5".

The Javascript line that starts with "{label" denotes one part of the Donut chart. Initially the data pulled from MySQL is done so with fetchArray(), what I am trying to do is to generate each "{label" line using a PHP foreach statement (eg. foreach($Array as $graph)) so that the graph can be generated dynamically based on the number of referrer names returned by fetchArray(). I've tried pretty much everything I can think of to make this work - storing the entire Javascript line in PHP and then echoing it out to Javascript, etc. But it always causes an internal error with PHP.

I'm sure the answer is right under my nose, thank you all for your time.

Comment: _"But it always causes an internal error with PHP"_, what is the error? What line of code does it point to?

Comment: It simply fails to execute, and shows an error 500

Comment: A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Look at the error log of the server, there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to generate a clean data object:

in PHP:

```
$data = array( array( 'label' => $graph["referrer"] ), 'value' => $graph["chart"] ) );
```

in your JavaScript;

```
data: <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this code leaves me with only "Google.com 2" whereas I am trying to generate the entire Javascript string from "{" to "}".

Comment: "Google.com 2" is definitely not the output `json_encode()` generates. Are you looking at the actual generated source code? Are you echoing it in the right place?

Comment: Ops my bad. Okay, so I think we're going somewhere. Here's my code for the loop: <?php foreach($Array as $graph): + Your PHP code above + echo json_encode($data); However the output is:

{"0":{"label":"Facebook"},"value":"2"}{"0":{"label":"Direct"},"value":"2"}{"0":{"label":"Microsoft"},"value":"1"}{"0":{"label":"Ask.com"},"value":"1"}{"0":{"label":"Google"},"value":"1"}

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of passing arrays of php variables to js scripts is using `json`. Here's what you need to do:

**php** part:

```
$sql = 'select * from ....';    // your query
// execute query
// as I don't know what mysql api do you use, 
// it's kinda pseudo-code
// but the main idea is to get all rows 
// you need in one array `$graphs`

$graphs = array();
while ($graph = fetch_array()) {
    $graphs[] = array(
        'label' => $graph["referrer"],
        'value' => $graph["chart"],
    );
}
```

**js** part:

```
<script>
Morris.Donut({
    element: 'css div',
    data: <?php echo json_encode($graphs); ?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So using the PHP variables in the Javascript was something I've already been able to figure out. I want PHP to generate an entire line starting with "{ label:" and ending with "}," for every instance of referrer name in the array. For the loop I'm using foreach($arrayofreferrers as $graph) so all I really need is to figure out how to put the entire Javascript code, with the PHP code, inside of a PHP echo. The foreach loop would then run the echo X the number of referrers mentioned in the $arrayofreferrers.

Comment: Though it's up to you to decide, but I strongly recommend you do what I answered. By the way - if you will have `label` value with `'` what will you get?

Comment: I'm trying your code, but it returns nothing. My array from the MySQL query is: Array ( [0] => Array ( [referrer] => Facebook [count] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [referrer] => Direct [count] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [referrer] => Microsoft [count] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [referrer] => Ask.com [count] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [referrer] => Google [count] => 1 ) )

So perhaps it's not working because I'm using a multidimensional array? Sorry, I don't understand your question about the label value '.

Answer (score 1):

You are not at all looping the `$graph` variables. It just has only one:

```
<script>
  Morris.Donut({
    element: 'css div',
    data: [{
      label: '<?php echo($graph["referrer"]); ?>',
      value: '<?php echo($graph["chart"]); ?>'
    },]
  });
</script>
```

The above code will render only one variable. I believe, you should have some kind of looping here:

```
<script>
  Morris.Donut({
    element: 'css div',
    data: [
<?php foreach (/* some loop */) { ?>
      {
        label: '<?php echo($graph["referrer"]); ?>',
        value: '<?php echo($graph["chart"]); ?>'
      },
<?php } ?>
    ]
  });
</script>
```

Or the best way is to use an array and `json_encode()` to output the JSON.

Comment: Sorry, my foreach code was around the <script> tags, so I forgot to paste it in. I have set it to "foreach $referrer as $graph", my loop needs to generate not only the values of the "label" and "value" Javascript tags, but the entire line itself by the number of referrers returned by MySQL.

So for each refferer returned I need PHP to print out:
{ label: '<?php echo ($graph["referrer"]); ?>', value: '<?php echo ($graph['value']); ?>' },

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was to concatenate the string together in a big, ugly but working glob.

```
<script>
Morris.Donut({
element: 'graph div'
data: {
<?php foreach($multidimarray as $graph): ?>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars("{label: "."'".$graph['referrer']."'".", value: "."'".$graph['count']."'"." }, "); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
]
});
</script>
```

Which returns as: 
    { label: 'Facebook', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Direct', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Microsoft', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Ask.com', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Google', value: '1' },

Again thank you all for your help, even though I didn't understand them I appreciate all of your answers. I will mark Gerald's answer because he responded first, mentioned json_encode first, and got me closest to the desired outcome.